# Altering Firebase reference depending on whether a node has child or not before loading data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-lifecycle

I am trying to set my Firebase reference before my child listener kicks in and loads my data. I know onCreate is ahead of onResume but my code below seems to contradict it as my reference is still what I have set in my onResume(). It seems like what I set up in onCreate doesn't go before what I have in onCreate().

Why is that?

I am trying to read from a template in my database if another node doesn't have the user registered as a child yet. 
Any hint would be appreciated.

p.s. I have logged out the references and the Log in OnResume() goes first as well.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.services_activity);


    app = FirebaseApp.getInstance();
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(app);
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(app);
    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance(app);
    username = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();


    databaseRef = database.getReference("serv_hst");
    servTempltRef = database.getReference("serv_tmplt"); 

    databaseRef.child(username).addChildEventListener(new   ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            //I am trying to set my reference that I will use in OnResume() ..!!

            if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                servTempltRef = database.getReference("serv_hst");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
        });           
        }

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


    servTempltRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override        
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The code inside the onChildAdded() will be executed asynchronously only when the data will be downloaded from Firebase Database.
So, after that the execution flow will execute the line in which there is the .addChildEventListener() method, it will go ahead and will continue to execute the next lines... 
In your case, the onCreate() has no other lines to be executed. So, due to the Activity lifecicle, the onResume() method will be executed without the data you need.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it's been awhile , I was pretty much a newbie back then , not that I'm not now. Appreciate the comment anyway